# convert string to long long int

Tags: c++

I want to read the 3rd line from a text file in as a `string`, convert it to a `long long int`, and return that value.

The data on the 3rd line of the text file is `1234567890123456`

```
long long int File::Getline3(int user1, int user3)
{
    std::string filename = std::to_string(user1);

    std::ifstream fin(filename + ".txt");
    fin.getline (line1, 5);
    fin.getline (line2, 5);
    fin.getline (line3, 20);
    fin.close();

    // convert line 3 to a string called str
    const char *line3;
    std::string str(line3);

    // convert str to long long int called user3
    long long int strtoll(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
    char* endptr = NULL;
    user3 = strtoll(str.c_str(), &endptr, 10);

    return user3;
}
```

The comments are in to show what I think I'm doing, however I am probably wrong (I'm new to pointers).

I get an "unresolved external" error when I try to build my program.

Comment: any answers with explanations of whats being done please

Comment: Code does not compile

Comment: it doesn't, error is "unresolved external"

Comment: Ummm, why are you declaring strtoll instead of `#include`-ing `cstdlib`? And why do you send in as argument `int user3` if you don't use it, just assign to it and return?

Comment: Are you sure of the requirements, are you sure your requirements say "read the 3rd line from a text file in as A char".  I think the intent might be to read it in as a string of chars, then perform your own conversion of that string into its integer form as would be held by the computer.

Comment: I've updated the question/title to make this more clear, since you *can't* read a line of text as a 'char' and since you really mean as a string.

Comment: I decided that the best way was to use a char, I've never heard of a string of chars before, will look into that now

Comment: @user3001499: You _are_ using strings of `char`s... Don't confuse `char` with `char*`. Which book are you using?

Comment: using a mixture of internet research (probably a bad idea in hindsight) and I'm currently just starting to use The Complete Reference C++ by Herbert Schildt (just arrived in the post 2 days ago)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
long long int strtoll(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
```

This line *declares* a function. It means that when you call `strtoll` a few lines down, you're going to be calling that function as it's the most obvious candidate. However, you never defined it.

Instead you meant to call `std::strtoll`, which *is* defined (by the standard library), and which will be found through your presumed `using namespace std` directive if you do not *hide* it by falsely declaring this non-existent function of your own with the same name. :)

Simply remove the excess declaration:

```
// convert str to long long int called user3
char* endptr = NULL;
user3 = strtoll(str.c_str(), &endptr, 10);
```

You have a similar issue with your `const char* line3`, which you declare inside the function, never assign anything to, then construct a string out of. That's undefined; the pointer is uninitialised. Assuming you have some `line3` data member (along with your `line1` and `line2`), again you're *hiding* it with a local variable of the same name.

Finally, passing `user3` in by value is utterly pointless if you're just writing to it and returning it. Remove that parameter.

Putting all this together, your code should probably look like:

```
// convert line3 to long long int
char* endptr = NULL;
return strtoll(line3, &endptr, 10);
```

In short, be less declaration-happy!

Comment: It now compiles at least, however the returned value is still not what is on line 3 of the text file, but 10 random digits, any suggestions?

Comment: also strtoll didnt work, through up an error saying it was undefined, so had to change it to strtol, which maybe why it isn't working correctly?

Comment: I'm not going to iteratively debug your program line by line in comments... but if you look at the manual for [`strtoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) you'll see it's in C++ only since C++11 (though if you were on Linux you should have had it anyway, via POSIX).

Answer (score 0):

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758053/missing-strtold-strtoll-strtoull-functions-from-stdlib-h

A work around for Visual C++ that does not have these included.

Comment: In generally, it is better to include content here rather than just link to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
long long int File::Getline3(int user1)
{
    std::string filename = std::to_string(user1);

    std::ifstream fin(filename + ".txt");

    std::string line1, line2; // place to actually store the lines

    getline(fin, line1); // read a line
    getline(fin, line2); // read another line

    long long int number_on_line_3; // somewhere to store the number
    fin >> number_on_line3;         // store the number
    fin.close();

    return number_on_line_3;        // return the number
}
```